# Creating a reusable javascript function instead of copy/paste

Tags: javascript, html

I made a page I need to have in different instances. In short it is used to fill in different parts of a script and then display said script on the page for the user to copy it.

This script below handles the main part of the job, getting a field from HTML and then i can call the result in html to be displayed.

```
var urlField = document.getElementById('urlField').value;
var resultUrl = document.getElementById('resultUrl');
resultUrl.textContent = urlField;
```

Problem: there are different fields, eg. url, startdate, enddate, adschedule, etc. so I **would like to have a reusable script that just says get the respective field and result the value which is assigned to it in html**.

Can I do this somehow? I was researching the function "this" in javascript, but it is too complicated for my current knowledge. Bear in mind that I am in only a very basic level.

You can find the whole codepen to understand the issue better here: https://codepen.io/kmb5/pen/GxZbZq

Comment: Create an array of id pairs, loop through them and update accordingly

Comment: You don't need to worry about `this` at all for this function. Try writing a function that takes in a string (such as 'urlField') and does the same thing as your snippet above. Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Defining_functions) for more information on writing functions.

Comment: @MikeC yeah that is exactly what I would like to do! But I am still not sure about the method, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters to your re-usable function and then call it whenever you need to use it. Use javascript to get the required data and pass it in as parameters.

reusable.js:

```
function myFuncWithParameters(parm1, parm2, parm3){

}
```

Alternatively:

```
function myFuncWithParameters(myObject){
    //access properties from the object: myObject.parm1, myObject.parm2, myObject.parm3
}
```

Using the object route might make it easier since the order of the properties will not matter like parameters. Regardless of either method you will have to validate the input.

In your html pages, you will need some More JavaScript and HTML to bring in the JS and call it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my page</title>
        <script scr="path to reusable js"></script>
        <script src="path to this path's js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        my page
    </body>
</html>
```

If you look at the script tags, by importing the reusable js you can use it in javascript that was written / imported further down into the page.

In order to ensure you have access to an imported function, you can check if the function you need is defined:

```
if(typeof(myFuncWithParameters) !== 'undefined' && typeof(myFuncWithParameters) == typeof(Function){
    //myFuncWithParameters will definitely be defined and is a function, if we get in here
}else{
    //myFuncWithParameters is not defined and/or is not a function
}
```

In your html page to call the re-usable function...

```
var parm1 = value;
var parm2 = value;
var parm3 = value;
myFuncWithParameters(parm1, parm2, parm3);
```

In you decide to use the object:

```
var myObject = {
    'parm1' : 4,
    'parm2' : 6
}
//myObject.parm1 == 4
myFuncWithParameters(myObject);
```